# How to compare strings within a function

Tags: python, string, return, function

I am trying to learn Python for fun. I'm doing an online lesson at codecademy.com, but I have no idea what I have to do.

I'm trying to compare 's' parameter with other parameter (string parameter), and the returned value should be "Sorry".

```
def shut_down(s):
    return s
    if s == 'yes':
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == 'no':
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```

so I call the function:

```
shut_down('lhagvbs')
```

It always returns, "Your function failed on the message yes. It returned 'yes' when it should have returned 'Shutting down'"

And i think my code does not work. Not even the def function is correct.

Please explain why, what, where, etc.

Sorry, I do not speak/write English well, but I hope it's understandable.

(This is not homework).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `return s` as you are returning `s` regardless, all the code after `return s` is unreachable so you never evaluate your if/elif or else:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == 'yes':
        return "Shutting down"
    elif s == 'no':
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    else:
        return "Sorry"
```

In keeping with the fact you can only return once from any function, you can  also forget the elif and else:

```
def shut_down(s):
    if s == 'yes':
        return "Shutting down"
    if s == 'no':
        return "Shutdown aborted"
    return "Sorry"
```

Comment: OMG . so easy i can not beleave that ...... thx man .. i am hanging there already 4 hour... hahah ... so return set the value of 's' withouth type 's' anwhere ....THX

Comment: @MartinŠanta,yes, you were simply returning whatever was passed in to the function every time  so everything after `return s`  would never have been reached